# How to make selenium-browser and manually opened browser have same behaviour?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I'm having a problem when trying to login to target.com with selenium. I have used firefox and chromium webdriver. It's always success with the browser that opened manually. But with selenium, it always failed.

The error happens when I submit the login form. It says "error T83072242".
I have attached the AJAX response that I get [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBU78.png).

After doing some analysis, I got a conclusion that [these variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ki1x.png) on `request header` is the one that caused the error. When I replace this variable with the one from the another browser(that I open manually), the ajax request is success.

So, how to make the selenium-browser behave like the normal browser?

Pardon for my english.

Comment: It seems your problem is solved. A selenium browser *is* a normal browser. You just need to load some of the data that your normal day-to-day browser has. Most of that is cookies.

Comment: It's the first thing to do on my mind.
I have load the cookies, and the profile too. But it didn't work.